# How to access a Subresource in a REST API without using the unique identifier?

Tags: rest, http, uri, api-design

I need to access a sub-resource of a resource without using the real unique identifier of that resource.

As far as I understood, you use Path-Variables for unique identifiers and Request-Params for filtering.

If I would use the unique identifier, the URI could look as follows:

```
/cars/47/engine/name
```

However if I want to obtain the name of the engine of a car by the color of the car, I am not sure how to do is. Since color would be a filter, the query would have to look something like this:

```
/cars?color=red/engine/name
```

But this looks kind of odd to me or is this actually the conventional way of doing it?

And furthermore, how would I use multiple properties of a resource as the unique identifier? Imagine I have an application where I could identify a person by it's firstname, sirname and the country that person was born in. Would I chain them together like that:

```
/persons/JoeWatsonSpain
```

Or wouldn't I be able to use it as a real unique identifier and do filter logic instead?

```
/persons?firstname=Joe&sirname=watson&country=spain
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*"But this looks kind of odd to me (`/cars?color=red/engine/name`) or is this actually the conventional way of doing it?"*

No. This API design is incorrect. According to [RFC3986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-3.4):

> The query component is indicated by the first question mark ("?") character and terminated by a number sign ("#") character or by the end of the URI.

Thus, you can't use query (or previous term in RFC1738, "searchpart") and end it with `/`.

The more appropriate way would be like:

```
/cars/engine/name?carColor=red
```

*"How would I use multiple properties of a resource as the unique identifier?"*

There are 2 options (maybe more):

1. "Chain them together", with your own separate rule. Such as: `/persons/Joe_SP_Watson_SP_Spain`
2. Use query as you mentioned. Such as `/persons?firstname=Joe&sirname=watson&country=spain`

Personally, I prefer the second solution, which is easier to understand and easier to maintain.

Comment: In the case of "/persons?firstname=Joe&sirname=watson&country=spain" would it be legit to only return one object or should I return an array?

Comment: You can return both. But obviously array is better as these are filters.

Answer (score 0):

> How to access a Subresource in a REST

What you are trying to access is not a sub-resource but attribute of the main resource itself. A sub-resource would have its own identity. For example, consider:

```
GET /company/{companyId}/employee/{employeeId}
```

Here, employee is a sub-resource. However, companyName is not a sub-resource but attribute of the main resource i.e company

---

> However if I want to obtain the name of the engine of a car by the color of the car...

When you are querying for cars with `color=red`, you should expect to get a list of resources (cars) in response as per REST standards.

So GET /cars?color=red should be expected to return list of cars [car1, car2, ...] matching the filter criteria of color=red.

To solve your problem, I won't be creating a separate endpoint on server side for getting engine names of the cars (emphasis plural for reason explained above) matching `color=red`. Instead I will ask the client (browser app, other consumers) to do that from the list of cars returned by GET /cars?color=red